# C++ type complementation in vscode extensions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am learning C++ on docker using the template project at https://github.com/cpp-best-practices/gui_starter_template in C++.

I have the following code, where `name:` and `text:`are not originally written
code, but it is completed so that I can see which type it is.
It is not a problem because it disappears when it is executed.
Which extension is this?
It is useful, but I would like to know which extension it is.
I use C++ better syntax, Clang tidy and Clang Format.

```
struct IMG : Tag
{
  explicit IMG(std::string url) : Tag{ name : "img", text : "" } { attributes.emplace_back(make_pair("src", std::move(url))); }
};
}// namespace html
```

Comment: This kind of editor feature is called *inlay hints*. You may be able to find related extensions by searching this term.

Comment: I know Clangd does this. Maybe the stock Microsoft's C/C++ extension does it too, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `inlay hints` is a built-in feature now. And VS Code introduced some new values to control how `inlay hints` behaves since [`v 1.67`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_toggle-inlay-hints) :

Editor › `Inlay Hints`: Enabled value:

- `on` - Inlay hints are enabled.
- `off` - Inlay hints are disabled.
- `onUnlessPressed` - Inlay hints shown and hidden with Ctrl+Alt.
- `offUnlessPressed` - Inlay hints hidden and shown with Ctrl+Alt.

Check this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/16221) for more detail about `inlay hints`

When I set `inlay hints` to `offUnlessPressed`, it looks like this while I press `Ctrl + Alt`(Please ignore that it's a Rust project):

[image]